# Applying Sepia via Renderscript ScriptIntrinsicColorMatrix turns image into Shades of green

Tags: android, opencv, renderscript, colorfilter

I am using the colormatrix intrinsic by Renderscript to apply a Sepia filter, however it turns the whole image green, rather than give it that yellowish tint (Sepia). The answer of this Thread is my current basis for testing (http://answers.opencv.org/question/99510/opencv4android-31-mat-to-allocation-renderscript/). A bitmap is turned into an OpenCV Mat then into an Allocation and passed onto renderscript where the following intrinsic does its work:

```
 Element element = Element.RGBA_8888(mRS);
 ScriptIntrinsicColorMatrix colorMatrix = ScriptIntrinsicColorMatrix.create(mRS, element);
 final Matrix4f mSepia = new Matrix4f(new float[]{
                0.189f, 0.769f, 0.393f, 0f,
                0.168f, 0.686f, 0.349f, 0f,
                0.131f, 0.534f, 0.272f, 0f,
                0.000f, 0.000f, 0.000f, 1f});
 colorMatrix.setColorMatrix(mSepia); 
 colorMatrix.forEach(inputAllocation, outputAllocation);
```

I exclude an error in this complicated Bitmap to Mat to Allocation process, because when I tried to run the intrinsic over a Bitmap directly a few weeks back I got the exact same green-tint problem.

I assume it should be a Vector (R,G,B,A) which is then multiplied by the Matrix I gave, but something fishy must be happening along the way.

Does anyone know what's happening here?

Comment: Is the source a Bitmap from a file or a Camera? If Camera shouldn't the data be in YUV format?

Comment: It comes from a Bitmap from a file. When I did this weeks ago I turned an OpenCV Mat rgba into a Bitmap argb_8888 and ended up with the same issue.

Comment: Update: I get the same weird green tint when streaming directly from the Camerafeed and letting Renderscript do the conversions (YUV to RGB and then apply colormatrix and convert to bitmap in order to show on screen). I am suspicious of the Bitmaps involved, maybe the way it saves the Pixels is different and causes weirdness.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV stores images using the B-G-R format, not the R-G-B one, so probably you just need to swap the B and R channels :)

Comment: If only it were this easy! Thanks for the suggestion though! :)

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time, but I think it was simply the wrong way to input the matrix. I think it had to be transposed. Renderscript simply expected the input in a different form.